# Read partitioned tables coming from dms into glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a partitioned table in the rds(postgres), this table is read by dms and put into dms along with other tables. So for the partitioned table dms creates a new folder each day on s3 in naming like this:

```
revenue/
revenue_y2022d001/
revenuey_2022d002
sales/
sales_y2022d001/
sales_y2022d002/
...
```

I want to read only all the sales tables in the glue dynamic dataframe.
There is a way to use exclusion in the crawler but then one crawler will need to be created for each partitioned table.
So is there a way to read only the folders starting with sales in the glue dynamic dataframe?

Comment: Have you tried connection_options = {"paths": [ "s3://mybucket/sales_y*"]} ?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy That throws error "regex not supported"